# How to copy a field in Classic Asp

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, cross-browser

We recently started supporting more browsers than just IE. Now I'm hunting for a quick fix for our website.

We have a billing address field and a shipping address field with a checkbox which is copies billing to shipping fields.

What works in IE looks like

```
response.write("<input type=""checkbox"" name=""SameAsSubmitter"" value=""Same"" onclick=""document.getElementById('ShipTo').value=document.getElementById('BillTo').value;""/>Same as Billing
```

On Firefox and Chrome this same code will generate the checkbox, but not return the document.GetElement What tips or tricks can I use to copy the billing fields to the shipping fields?

Comment: Not really a classic asp question.  Your response write statement outputs a bit of javascript and this is about how different browsers handle that javascript on the client side.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how a browser interprets JavaScript.

Comment: @Greg How is that off-topic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the fields where never given an Id in the first place and a quirk of IE is that it will check the field's Name in place of Id if none is assigned.

Answer (score 0):

It's case sensitive.

Change `document.getElementByID('ShipTo')` to `document.getElementById('ShipTo')`

Comment: I freehanded my example. The above code works for ID (I just double checked and indeed misstyped the example.)

Comment: Then your ASP should generate code like here: http://jsfiddle.net/p220pba6/ and it works (type something in second textbox and check the checkbox) - and it *doesn't* work for uppercase ID

Comment: Turns out the fields where never given Id's, just Names. IE apparently gave the Name if no Id was provided! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No prob. Glad the answer was helpful. Sometimes you just need a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Um, I appreciate downvite - every experience count, I guess, but I would never learn if I don't know the reason for it. Please teach me.